# Node Express Routing Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I´m currently trying to render my .ejs-templates with some variables, but I´m kinda stuck and can`t help myself. I´ve installed express over the express-generator with compass and ejs.

In my routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.write('Hello World')
  res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

So I want to render <%= name %> in index.ejs (views/index.ejs) with the name Jack. In a few tutorials it should work this way, but it just don`t works for me.

I got an error telling me that the variable name is not defined. Would be very nice, if you guys could tell me, what I´m doing wrong or what I´ve missed.
I´m using ejs the first time and just can`t figure out my mistake =/

This is my app.js server-file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require("http");

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('node-compass')({mode: 'expanded'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});



module.exports = app;
```

regards,
Cab

edit: I figured out that the rendering of the variable title works, but all the other variables don`t work. I can imagine, that I can only access some kind of global variables and title is one of them =/

edit2: Found out, that my routing isn`t working properly ... so the rendering isn`t working ofc. But can`t figure out my mistake =/

Comment: Is it show any errors in `console`?

Comment: It`s only showing an error, when I´m trying to insert variables. Than it`s telling me for example: name is not defined. But it`s kinda defined within the res.render. So when I´m using <%= title %> its replacing it with Express, but it`s not taking the variables from my routes. When I´m trying to using the routes variables it is always telling me ... variable xyz not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have split your project up into different modules then you need to export those modules so they are available in other parts of your app.
For example you have separate route modules where you are defining your routes. For these to be available to the rest of your app then you need to make them available using the `module.exports` command.

so at the end of `routes/index.js` you need to have

```
module.exports = router;
```

The end of the [express page](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) on routing gives an example

Comment: Sorrry, my fault ... forget to copy/paste the line with module.exports = router; I`ve used the express-generator for my app and haven`t changed anything in the routing, (version: 4.12.4).